# css selector for many child tags

Tags: css

I know it can be done like:

```
#details > tbody > tr > td:last-child > input ,
#details > tbody > tr > td:last-child > select
{
...
}
```

Is there a better way? Something closer to:

```
#details > tbody > tr > td:last-child > (input, select)
{
...
}
```

Comment: No, there isn't. But you could just omit most of the `>` and child-selectors, the only content for a `table` *has* to be within `td` or `th` tags, so all the rest are only rarely required.

Comment: @DavidThomas Yes and no.  The tr could be omitted (as you say, td/th elements must be children of tr elements), but it is not unusual to style a th within a thead different from a th within a tbody.  If the OP has nested tables, then none of it can be omitted.

Comment: I strongly recommend using classes for situations like these.

Comment: I have to say, this being the first question I ever ask here... you guys are fast! :) On topic: @user2620860: In general, that might be the best option, however, I don't always like the class approach because sometimes I'm already using a class in the markup for other purposes... In my experience class attributes like "class1 class2 class3" are harder to read and make the markup a lot uglier...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  CSS offers no such thing.  A CSS Preprocessor (Sass, LESS, etc.) could make it simpler to *write* such a selector, but the generated CSS will be exactly what you already have.

```
#details > tbody > tr > td:last-child {
    > input, > select {
        // styles
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't anything like this. In addition, you're overqualifing your selectors and this lead to poor performance.

If you want to use a more expressive language to write your CSS, use [SCSS](http://sass-lang.com/) instead.

Comment: I didn't know over-qualifying was a "bad practice" in CSS... I always tend to qualify as much as possible, since I believe it makes the code easier to understand...

Answer (score 0):

Without more context the answer is no. For specific examples it might be possible to write equivalent selectors that are shorter, for example

```
#details > tbody > tr > td:last-child > :not(div)
```

but you should avoid this because it makes for brittle styles (prone to introducing unintended effects when your markup changes).

Just go with what works.